# mysql function syntax no query specified

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select, where-clause

the function is this:

```
delimiter |

create function average() returns int
    begin 
        declare AB int;
        set AB= avg(attribute1) from tablename where attribute2='AMG' ;
        return AB; 
    end; 
|

ERROR    No query specified
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER | 

    CREATE FUNCTION   average()
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN DECLARE AB INT;
    SELECT AVG(attribute1) INTO AB FROM tablename WHERE attribute2='AMG' ;
    RETURN AB; END; |
```

Comment: You are awesome. It works!!!   Thanks. 
But what i did wrong? Is it wrong to use 'SET' in a function?

Comment: @user3153534 You're most welcome... You have syntax error in your query. If you got desired output and an active member of stackoverflow try to accept and upvote the answer. How to use stackoverflow take a tour of that on this link http://stackoverflow.com/tour. It will describe how to accept and upvote the answer.